# getting a could not resolve host error when trying to install RVM on osx lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion, rvm

I have all the prereq's installed.. I am on osx lion 10.7.2

**xcode:**

```
$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 4.2.1
```

**git:**

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.5.4
```

when i run
    $ bash < <( curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm )

i get the following error:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: HD; nodename nor servname provided,
>   or not known Could not download
>   'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tarball/master'.

any ideas why? If i run as sudo it goes through but then i get more errors... Need this to install as single user. path to my home dir is:

```
'/volumes/Macintosh HD/users/mikedevita'
```

Comment: i have a feeling that this is because my hdd name is Macintosh HD...

Comment: I think you're right. If you check out the script - it's failing because `curl` is choking on your `$rvm_path`, which includes your home directoy. It can't handle the space in the path to your home directory (and consequently `$rvm_path`

Comment: yup, got rvm installed.. but the GUI jewelrybox is force closing every time it opens..

Comment: i down graded to 1.1.2 and JewelryBox is loading now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the file brew is referring to has moved, hence you are looking for a dead link.

I got past this issue by running 'brew update' in the terminal.

After letting this run, and after brew updates to the latest version it should have the latest directories and files, and as a result should avoid dead links. You should be free to continue as normal now.