# Could not resolve host when trying to install RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to install RVM on my environment following the instructions on RVM page

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

but I always get this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0    198      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   246
100  9979  100  9979    0     0   3821      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 14740
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: github.com; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I've got the same error when trying to install gems before trying RVM. Some people say it's a network problem, but I can't figure out what it is. I'm new to ruby and trying to setup my environment to work with rails.

I've tried to ping github.com and most packets went fine with less than 10% loss.

So is this really a problem with my network? If so, how can I fix this?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.

**Update:**

Definitely, it's some problem in my network configuration on Mac OS X. I can't run commands on git or svn. I always get the 'could not resolve hostname' error. Need some investigation on that.
Have someone ever had the same problem? So I could try to change something on my network configuration.

Comment: do you have an account on github? try `ssh -vT git@github.com` and look for anything peculiar

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842306

Comment: you need git-core installed if you haven't done so already. The command I use `bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )`

Comment: @Simon git is installed and working fine. That command gives me the same error.
@PriteshJ I've checked that before, but it doesn't help me.
@prusswan Yes, I have an account on github. I tried that command and it returned the same error:
`OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: Well, to confirm that it's probably a problem with my network, I've just installed rvm and ruby with complete success just using the 3G connection shared from my iPhone. But I still can't figure out what's the problem with my network setup. I'm connected through WiFi to a router, and this router is wired to a modem. The modem has a firewall. And that's it. Should I modify something on this configuration?

Comment: It looks like a DNS or proxy problem. From your last comment, you are not using proxy. Change your DNS servers to [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) and try again.

Comment: @SonySantos Valeu, cara! :) That worked perfectly! But why do I need to use that in order to get git and svn working? I haven't read anything about that before... On pc with windows everything works, but in my mac I was having that problem. I think you should write that as an answer, so I can mark yours as correct. Thanks again, man!

Comment: I'm using Google DNS, Ubuntu 13.04 - still couldn't resolve the HOST get.rvm.io :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a DNS or proxy problem. From your comments, you are not using proxy. Change your DNS servers to [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) and try again.

That problem is not related to git or svn, so you won't find info about DNS on their sites. It's due to network config, network availability or internet provider (likely the former).

Comment: I ran into this problem from a Hotel network. @Sony Santos' recommendation helped solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try running as sudo; worked for me! I know its not ideal, but proves that it may be a permissions problem.