# SSH connect to github fail

Tags: github, ssh

I typed the command to have a connection test to `github`:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

but it outputs:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

why ssh could not resolve github.com? I want to know this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 22):

Check your network or dns config (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11937157/6309)).
"[git and ssh: Could not resolve hostname, ping works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058758/6309)" mentions:

> This sounds like a DNS issue. Try switching to another DNS server and see if it works.

```
OpenDNS

    208.67.222.222
    208.67.220.220

GoogleDNS

    8.8.8.8
    8.8.4.4
```

If ssh still gives you hard time, try switching to https.

---

The [OP Edlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1872675/edlin) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488137/ssh-connect-to-github-fail/21496307?noredirect=1#comment32455420_21496307) that switching DNS works, and recommend for Mac OS X users the [How-to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/) article "[How to Switch Mac OS X to Use OpenDNS or Google DNS](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38793/how-to-switch-mac-os-x-to-use-opendns-or-google-dns/)":

> - System Preferences…
> - click on the Network icon…
> - select your network card on the left and then select the Advanced button near the bottom right corner.
> - switch over to the DNS tab, and you can start adding in DNS entries into the list.
>     Click the `+` symbol at the bottom to add new ones:

[image: http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/up/sshot4d0b1298a026e.jpg]

Comment: Jesus! It works. Thanks you! And here is a link about [How to Switch Mac OS X to Use OpenDNS or Google DNS](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38793/how-to-switch-mac-os-x-to-use-opendns-or-google-dns/). It may help someone who need it.

Comment: @Edlin Excellent. I have referenced and illustrated in the answer the link you mention for more visibility.